# Is there any software that will print a .pgn file in scoresheet layout

Tags: pgn

I'm looking for some software that will print the moves as

```
1. e4 e5    
2. Nf3 Nc6  
3. Bb5 Nf6
```

etc.

Instead of

```
1.e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Nf6
```

etc.

Comment: "Print" on screen or on paper?

Comment: On paper to take down to the club and show to our expert

Comment: I could quickly write you a software which does this (for free of course). Message me if you need it so badly :)

Answer (score 1):

Scid can export to pgn, LaTeX and HTML. During export you have the option ''Column style (one move per line)? Yes/No''

I just tried it and it works for all three export formats. That's for scid version 4.6.4 on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered that Fritz (which I have) also has a "Print Scoresheet" option. Thanks to everyone who answered.